# Correlation within groups

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation

I have a dataset with 200 variables. Each row of my data represents the quarter results of a company. I want to know if variable X is linearly related to variable Y.

I computed the correlation matrix without any grouping but now that I think of it seems weird to me. Should I be including any type of grouping and then pooling to get the correlation of two variables (given that I know they have a grouped nature)?

| quarter | company | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020Q2 | ABC | 22 | 23 | 21 |
| 2020Q2 | XYZ | 2 | 84 | 22 |
| 2020Q2 | DEF | 1 | 22 | 23 |
| 2021Q1 | ABC | 11 | 43 | 24 |
| 2021Q1 | XYZ | 3 | 64 | 25 |
| 2021Q1 | DEF | 2 | 84 | 26 |
| 2019Q1 | ABC | 22 | 23 | 27 |
| 2019Q1 | XYZ | 2 | 84 | 28 |
| 2019Q1 | DEF | 2 | 84 | 29 |

... etc

Comment: "Should you" depends entirely on what question you're trying to answer. You can find whether X and Y are associated in general, or for a specific company over time, or across companies for a specific time, etc. - none of these are inherently the "correct" way to analyze the data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @NuclearHoagie! I want to know if variables X and Y are highly correlated in general, I just found odd to not group or anything knowing the inherent structure of the data.